# Could lithium deuteride sustain a "cold" chain reaction?

Tags: fusion, neutrons, cold-fusion

When Lithium 6 absorbs a neutron (thermal or not) it reacts forming an alpha particle and a tritium. The formed tritium has an average kinetic energy of 2.5 MeV. That kinetic energy is way higher than the Coulomb barrier for the D-T fusion reaction (around 100keV). The D-T fusion reaction produces an alpha particle and a neutron.
Hence a chain reaction could be possible in Lithium6-Deuteride where each neutron reacts with Lithium 6 producing a tritium that will react with deuterium producing a neutron etc.

I see 2 main problems (suppose infinite volume to neglect border effects):

1. The neutron will not always be captured by the Lithium 6 (when each one should be to sustain the reaction) but that could be potentially solved by putting some Beryllium 9 in the mix. When beryllium absorbs a high energy neutron (the kind produced by D-T fusion) it might split into two alpha particles and two neutrons. Also when beryllium fuses with an alpha particle (as produced by Li6 + n and D + T reactions) it will produce a Carbon 12 and a neutron. So a multiplying of neutrons is possible to some extent.
2. The tritium will scatter into the solid and lose its kinetic energy before having had the chance to fuse. (the alpha particles trying to fuse with Beryllium 9 will encounter the same problem)

I think the most limiting factor will be the second one. (The tritium won't undergo fusion because of too much scattering) Am I right ? And how could you calculate that ?

(The general idea was to use the Li6 + n reaction to catapult a tritium in a deuterium environment with enough energy to fuse and without using particle accelerators)

Comment: Well, go to ENDF, collect the various cross sections, and see at a high level (without detailed calculations) how reasonable this is.